# C++ Reading in User Input without the commas

Tags: c++, validation, input, user-input

I'm currently working on a homework assignment for my C++ class to make a multi-player Tic-tac-toe game but I'm having trouble with the input part of the program (I've got almost everything else running).

Anyway, my goal is to prompt the current player for a row and a column in the format row,col. Then I need to place their mark in a two dimensional array that represents the game board.

I thought that I could simply read their input into a char array using cin and then take the 0 position and 2 position in that array and I would have my two numbers from their input. However, if I do this, I end up with the ASCII values of the input, not the number (for example, I get 49 instead of '1').

I feel like I'm probably overlooking something really simple, so any input would be very helpful and much appreciated. Here is what I had:

```
void getEntry(char XorO, char gameBoard[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    char entry[3];

    cout << XorO << " - enter row,col: ";
    cin >> entry;

    int row = entry[0];
    int col = entry[2];

    //Then I would use the row, col to pass the XorO value into the gameBoard
}
```

Comment: Can you use `std::string` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are reading into a `char` array. When you convert the individual `char`s into `int`s, you will get the ASCII (or Unicode) values of the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, or `'2'`, not the integer values `0`, `1`, or `2`. To convert a single digit, you can use a useful property of ASCII codes: digit characters are sequential. This means that you can sutract the code for `'0'` from any digit to get the corresponding integer value. For example

```
row = entry[0] - '0';
```

Comment: Oh, that explains it, not subtracting zero, but rather the value for zero, that makes sens why that would work. Thank you!

Comment: @user2001427 It is very important for a C++ programmer to be aware of the type of data used. There is a *huge* difference between representing zero as a `char` (`'0'`) and representing zero as an `int` (`0`). The same goes for any other single digit.

Comment: Type doesn't really matter it all boils down to numbers :P What you're referring to is literal values. As far as the compiler and computer is concerned '0' is just 48. I can do `char c = 48;` and get the same result as `char c = '0';`

Comment: @JesusRamos Which is exactly the meaning of the `char` type. By your example, type *does* matter. It's the reason that the two initializations have the same result.

Comment: @Code-Guru Not really, types are just container sizes (except for the case of signed and unsigned which changes usage), C++ focuses on type so much people forget what's they're actually storing. Something like `char *` is not necessarily a string but can also be a pointer to a byte buffer which you don't want to interpret as characters.

Comment: @JesusRamos Type is more than just the size of the data. It is also the interpretation of that data. A `char*` is neither a string nor a byte buffer. It's a number which is interpreted as a memory address. What the data at that address means is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: @Code-Guru Again not necessarily true. If I don't need full storage size for 4 bytes I can use a 1 byte `char` and just use that as standard numbers. The only "type" enforcement here would be value restriction due to the size of a char.

Comment: @JesusRamos C++ allows these contortions of "type", yes. We are very likely using the same word in similar, yet subtly different, ways.

Comment: @Code-Guru C++ likes to give a notion of type where non exists :P You just have values restricted by size and signedness and nothing more, at least when dealing with primitives. It's still C at it's core.

Comment: @JesusRamos So you define "type" as what the compiler enforces. I also (typically) include the human constraints which we add on top of that which may or may not be enforced by the compiler or run-time system.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number just do

```
row = entry[0] - '0';
col = entry[2] - '0';
```

This will convert from ASCII to the actual digit.

Comment: Oh wow, that was incredibly simple. Thank you very much. I can't believe I just spent almost two hours trying to find an answer for that. I'm just curious, why does simply subtracting '0' convert it to the actual character?

Comment: @user2001427 See [my anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466053/c-reading-in-user-input-without-the-commas/14466131#14466131) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let `operator>>` deal with interpreting the numbers:

```
void getEntry(char XorO, char gameBoard[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    int row, col;
    char comma;

    cout << XorO << " - enter row,col: ";
    std::cin >> row >> comma >> col; 

    if( (!std::cin) || (comma != ',') ) {
      std::cout << "Bogus input\n";
      return;
    }

    //Then I would use the row, col to pass the XorO value into the gameBoard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void getEntry(char XorO, char gameBoard[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    char entry[3];

    cout << XorO << " - enter row,col: ";
    cin >> entry;

    int row = entry[0] - '0';
    int col = entry[2] - '0';

    //if grid_size <= 9
}
```

Comment: Right, Grid_Size is a constant that allows me to change the game from 3 x 3 to a 4x4 or higher.